# Where does PostgresSql localtime come from?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've inherited a PostgreSQL database backup that was created with a version around 9.3. During the restore I'm getting the following error: "[archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "localtime". The error occurs while calling CREATE FUNCTION that contains `SET "TimeZone" TO 'localtime'`.

I've tried restoring with 9.3, 9.4, and 14 and always get the same error. I've found other postings about this problem but they are all on Linux systems and I'm on Windows.

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: Please see if this helps explain the situation and gives clues to how to fix it:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/312871/211987

Comment: @MikeOrganek, thanks for pointing this out, but it's not clicking for me. My postgress timezone is set to my local timezone. Are you suggesting I set it to something else?

Comment: I am not suggesting that you set it to something else.  Get an interactive session open to your database and issue `set "TimeZone" to 'localtime'`.  If that gives you an error, then solve for that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but the simple solution was just to copy one of the files in the timezone directory and rename to localtime.

Answer (score 2):

What time zones you can use depends on how your time zone database is set up. Obviously on the original system there was a `localtime` time zone; probably a symbolic link to some other time zone.

You have two options:

1. use `ALTER FUNCTION` on the original system to change the time zone of the function to something else or edit the dump to change the function definition there
2. create a symbolic link called `localtime` to the time zone of your choice in the time zone database on the new system

   First, find out if PostgreSQL is built to use the operating system's copy of the time zone data base or its own copy. The former is the case if you see the `--with-system-tzdata` option set in the output of `pg_config --configure`.

The first solution would be better in my opinion.

Comment: going with the 2nd option, we've done a ```mklink localtime timezone\UTC``` in the postgres share directory and restarted the server, but still getting the same error. Anything you can think of that we may be missing? We do not see ```--with-system-tzdata``` in the config output.

Comment: Hmph, Windows. No idea if `mklink` is the right think here... Perhaps `mklink /h`? Fundamentally, you did the right thing, and on Linux a symbolic link works just fine.

Comment: We weren't able to get the symlink to work, but it triggered an idea to try simply copying one of the other timezone files and naming it localtime -- it worked!!